# check if method is static from metaclass

Tags: python, methods, static, metaclass

I have a use case where I use a metaclass to decorate instance methods of a class.

```
class DecoratedMeta(type):

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super(DecoratedMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            if mcs.is_valid(getattr(cls, attr_name)):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, mcs.decorate(getattr(cls, attr_name))) 
        return cls
```

The method `is_valid` should determine, amongst others, whether the underlying attribute is an instance method of `cls` (or one of its base classes) or a static class of `cls` (or one of its base classes).

`getattr` returns instance methods and static methods as functions. So how do I determine whether it is static or instance method?

I cannot only rely on `cls.__dict__` only because it does not contain the attributes of the base classes, and I would rather not manually inspect the `__dict__` of all classes in the inheritance tree.

I have currently solved this by inspecting whether the first argument of the method is `self`, but is there a better way?

Comment: Use `inspect.getattr_static()`; it'll handle the MRO traversal for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info Martijn. `getattr_static` is exactly what I needed.